# Loading raw component html output via Ajax in Joomla

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I  have a joomla component for which I need to implement a "load more" pagination in a Twitter fashion. What I do not know exactly how to do, is how do I get the component's HTML by using the same output from `view.html.php`, but without surrounding markup (i.e. modules, and template). I'm not sure if `loadTemplate()` will do the job.

Comment: use tmpl=component at the end of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the parameters:

```
?tmpl=component
```

or

```
?format=raw
```

to the query string.

The first will load a file named `component.php` in your template's folder, which is present in most templates and doesn't load extra scripts.

The latter just outputs the bare component output without any template at all, and should be your preferred choice.